# Critique on Composition I made

Tags: composition, jazz, blues

I was hoping someone with a solid background in jazz music theory to give me a solid critique on a jazz blues composition I made last month. Here's the link:

https://musescore.com/user/6040626/scores/6551517?share=copy_link

If the link doesn't work, go to MuseScore and in the search bar, type "Waldario Blues", and my score should pop up.

Comment: Although off-topic for the Q&A part of the site, you can post in the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

The players might appreciate double barlines and rehearsal letters to mark the sections.  Also chord symbols throughout.

Did you consider a snap ending on the last 8th of 160?

(The topic will probably get moved somewhere soon.)